# Query on tag with wildcard doesn't retrieve the questions if there is only one match

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-watching, wildcards

I couldn't find a similar question, forgive me if this is a duplicate. To illustrate the problem, I'll use the following example on SO:

We previously had `java-ee`, `java-ee-5`, `java-ee-6` questions so I have `java-ee*` in my list of interesting tags which is translated into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee~ (`java-ee` or `java-ee-5` or `java-ee-6`).

But `java-ee-5` and `java-ee-6` questions have been retagged now and `java-ee` is the only tag left. The problem is that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee~ (`java-ee` or '') returns 0 questions while there are many (504+) questions with the [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) tag.

IMO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee~ should return the 504+ questions as well.

Comment: confirm. the link you give returns 0.  this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-e~) gets all of them; note the single-character difference.  (oops, except it also gets a few other tags.  not quite as useful as i thought.)

Comment: @quack Indeed, but as you noticed java-e~ matches more than one tag. The bug is when there is only one match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an extra "or" being added to the end of the wildcard explode operation, which was preventing the single result case from working. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Yeahhh, it's working again!